# Database not accept Cyrillic character

Tags: java, mysql, spring, encoding

I have issue with Cyrillic character in database, and usage it java spring.

From chrome-browser image:
[image]

I create my database in next way:

```
create database dbname
character set utf8
collate utf8_general_ci;
```

Example database table:
(created automatically):

```
@Entity(name = "words")
public class Words {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "word")
    private String word;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
   }
```

Save entity way:

```
@Repository
public interface WordRepository extends JpaRepository<Word, Long> {
}
```

+

```
@Service 
public class WordService{

    @Autovired
    private WordRepository wordRepository;

    public saveAll(List<Word> wordList){
        wordRepository.saveAll(wordList);
    }
}
```

application.properties :

```
#Database settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.datasource.tomcat.connection-properties=useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf-8;
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

But, in result, when I save in database Cyrillic characters, all shows as '?'.

What else I must to do for resolve this?

Comment: See "question marks" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Most of it looks fine to me. How did this data get into the database?

Comment: Saved with method  <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> var1);
extending from CrudRepository interface

Comment: If you insert the data directly from a SQL editor it also appears with '???' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove **amp;** from string

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
```

in application.properties file.

Comment: I not understand where I take it!